# Handling multi tabs in a web application

Tags: html, web, tabs, firebug, security

In my web application, a user can rate a product via the product page. 
He can also open multiple tabs in his browser.

What is the best practice to allow him to rate a different product on each tab ?

- My first thought was to put the product id in session : bad idea since all the tabs share the same session and there's no way to know which tab is active (maybe it's possible ?).
- My second thought was to put in the page a hidden field containing the id of the product. This is the solution I kept for the moment. But a malicious user could change the id via firebug or some other tool.

So I was wondering, is there a better way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you mean that you want to force the user to see/rate different products, instead of the same product multiple times.

Quite simply, the enforcement should be done on the server side.  If the user is found to have already rated an id, the other requests to rate should return an error message (perhaps some http status in the 400 range).

You can get fancy with id and sessions, but the user can always do session playback.  Again, at the very basic level, you need the server-side check.

Without it, an innocent user could simply hit submit twice accidentally and you'd be running into the same problem.  The fact that there are multiple tabs have nothing to do with it.

Comment: Thanks, you assumed correctly. I finally added a server-side control with a database constraint in order to prevent this to happen.